# Can I buy a Maserati

Tags: halal-haram

Asalamualaikum,
I would like to buy  a maserati but am not sure regarding the symbol which is a Trident. Maserati is made in Modena, Italy today, but they were founded in Bologna. One of Bologna's most famous symbols is the fountain that depicts Neptune, a god of the seas, complete with his signature trident. The Maserati logo is inspired by this powerful icon, which symbolizes mastery over the water's raw power. That is what it said on google. With this being said would I be allowed to buy it if I don't believe in the stuff it means  as a muslim? Jazakallah

Comment: [Is it haram to drive an alfa romeo?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61554/is-it-haram-to-drive-an-alfa-romeo) is somewhat related.

Answer (score 0):

The car you drive is not who you are . I am driving a car that is made by Germans; that doesn’t mean that is part of my identity . I am Muslim and believer of Allah . As long as I am not boastful and dismiss people and look down on them . Belongings of mine doesn’t change my pride I myself like I’m better than people . You have to remember you identity as Muslim , treat people kindly .
As far as your closeness to Allah , level of your carefulness is up to you . For example some people eat halal and some don’t . Some pray and some don’t . Some wear hijab and some don’t . Some don’t do any dealings with interest and some don’t believe it’s wrong . If you are seeking closeness to Allah you can choose to do it all and avoid all that might be controversial . You have free will and intellectual mind . Make your choices wisely to choose your hereafter

Comment: So in this case would it be considered as Makrooh?